# Why commands don't work in IDEA terminal?

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, terminal

I use idea to write programs in java and pack it with maven. Java works fine, maven works fine but I cannot write commands in idea terminal like `git status`, `mvn package` it says this is not a command. I can perform git actions with special buttons and maven clean package with a maven menu in top right corner, but why can't I type commands in idea? It worked before but suddenly stopped.

Comment: What do you mean by "it says this is not a command"? Please show the exact error message.

Comment: it says git is not an inner or outer command or in russian - "git" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

And yes some update - before that terminal did not appear at all, it was written "cannot open local terminal failed to start powershell.exe"l, I tried writing way to powershell  in system 32 in terminal settings but no success, it started to work when I typed way to cmd (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe) in terminal settings and it appeared, but commands do not work.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with PATH variable. Please show your terminal settings (https://i.imgur.com/t9w0uRv.png. Windows restart could also be helpful here

Comment: Yes, there was some mess with path in environments,when I first tried to do a spring project, suddenly jdk was lost. What must be written in path? 
Java works fine and maven packs projects, but I have to use buttons. 

My terminal settings - https://ibb.co/N11hZvG

Comment: any fixes ? same problem

Comment: No, I haven't managed to fix it yet. I assume some problems with windows and messed PATH variable.

Comment: Some late update, terminal in idea works, but only with java commands like java -version, javac -version, it seems that problem is in maven or git installation, even in cmd commands starting with mvn do not work. Git works in git bash, but not in cmd or idea terminal.

Comment: And yes, it is at last fixed, problem was messed up Path variable, after I added properly maven, windows 32, windows 32 powershell into path variable maven commands started to work both in cmd and in idea. I am pretty sure properly adding git there will fix git issue as well.